# Firebase Security rules, disable write on specific node

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

My firebase structure looking like that:

```
{
"post": {
    "uid": {
        "text": "Name";
    }
},
"games": {
    "id": {
        "title": "buttons",
        "text": "(user id string)"
    },
    "id": {
        "title": "navbars",
        "text": "(id string)"
    }
},
"guides": {
    "1": {
        "title": "guide",
        "text": "unwriteable string"
    }
}
}
```

(The value doesn't matter..)

I want to allow read and write on everynode, **execpt** the guides node,

so I tried the following rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth == null",
    ".write": "auth == null",
      "guides": {
        ".write": false
      }
  }
}
```

But. unfortunately, because of the 'father' allowance, firebase doesn't care about the guides specific rule,

Any idea how to achive my goal?

Comment: Did you mean `auth != null`? `auth == null` is the same thing as `true`

Comment: @Kato I don't think it's the same as true. If I'm correct with that rule only people **without** authentication can write.

Answer (score 4):

Bacause [firebase security rules cascade](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/#section-authorization) you can't say someone has permission to write everywhere and later say but not here.

So in you case you would have to add rules for your other paths like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth == null",
      "guides": {
        ".write": false
      },
      "games": {
        ".write": "auth == null"
      },
      "post": {
        ".write": "auth == null"
      }
  }
}
```

As Kato stated this can also be done with the following rule:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth == null",
    ".write": "auth == null && !newData.hasChild('guides')"
  }
}
```

The first example will allow you to write only in the `games` and `post` nodes whereas the second example will allow you to write everywhere except for the `guides` node.

Comment: Definitely the best approach but not technically accurate if we want to split hairs. You could put something like this at root:  `".write":  "auth != null && !newData.hasChild('guides')"`

Comment: @Kato You are correct. I based this answer on the structure in the question. Personally i like to limit the opportunities for abuse. I'll update the answer tomorrow when i have more time or you can do it if you like.

Comment: I don't think that approach is abuse, although it's probably easy to get into trouble with. Imagine the use case where I have 50 paths but only want to restrict read on one of them. It's definitely overkill to have to write 49 `".read": true` rules : )

Comment: @Kato I updated the answer. Feel free to correct any mistakes i made.